# How can I correct this error in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using mfc which I compiled in Visual Studio 2010, and I am getting the following error:

```
error C2664: 'memmove' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CString' to 'void *'
```

My code is:

```
CString testArray[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    testArray[i].Format("%d", i*4);
}

memmove(testArray[2], testArray[3], sizeof(testArray)-2*sizeof(testArray[0]));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    MessageBox(testArray[i]);
}
```

How can I correct this error in mfc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not error in the MFC. Error is in your code, which is completely invalid. 
Lets look at it carefully:

> memmove(testArray[2], testArray[3],
>   sizeof(testArray)-2*sizeof(testArray[0]));

1. Using low-level memory copy routines like `memmove` with the complex data types is a sure proof way to failure. A class like `CString` may use a dynamical memory allocation and directly overriding its memory could cause any kind of trouble, beginning from the memory leakage and ending with immediate application failure. If you want to copy `CString` data use its own methods: `CString::Insert`, `CString::Replace`, assignment operator or copy constructor.
2. `memmove` function takes two pointers to the source and destination memory blocks. You are trying to pass two `CString` instances instead. Of course this is invalid and never would pass a compiler type check. This is an [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) of the correct `memmove` usage.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much!

Comment: You are right! This is not error in the MFC.
Error is in my code, which is completely invalid.
So, I have corrected it like this:
memmove(testArray+2, testArray+3, sizeof(testArray)-2*sizeof(testArray[0]));

Comment: DONT use raw functions with CString

Comment: Use `CStringArray`. Don't try to reinvent the wheel please.